# No binding using ngClass with map zoom event in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typescript, angular

I have this:

```
<i [ngClass]="{'active': isGeoLocationButtonEnabled }" class="toggle fa fa-crosshairs" >
```

And the handler is:

```
private onStartZoomEvent(event) {
    if (event.zoom != 12) {
        console.log("Current zoom level is: ", event.zoom);
        this._eventAggregator.trigger(new DisableGeolocationEvent());
        this.disableGeolocationButton();
    }
}
```

The event that is triggered looks like this:

```
private mapZoomChangedHandler() {
    this._mapsWrapper.getMap().then((map: google.maps.Map) => {
       let zoom = map.getZoom();
       this._eventAggregator.trigger(new MapStartZoomEvent(zoom));
    });
}
```

I am subscribing like this:

```
  this._eventAggregator.subscribe(MapStartZoomEvent, this.onStartZoomEvent.bind(this));
```

The problem is that for the first time I change the map zoom, the button is not disabled. The second time I click it , it gets disabled. When I debug, everything seems to be ok, my boolean isGeoLocationButtonEnabled is set to false, but the active class stays (it is just the background color highlighting).

Comment: How (and where) do you initialize the `isGeoLocationButtonEnabled` property?

Comment: public isGeoLocationButtonEnabled: boolean = false; also in the constructor   this.isGeoLocationButtonEnabled = false; neither works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show where `isGeoLocationButtonEnabled` is updated. I'm pretty sure that the Google Maps code runs outside Angulars zone.

Use `zone.run(...)` to run the code that updates the model inside Angulars zone so change detection is invoked afterwards

```
constructor(private zone:NgZone) {}

methodWhereEnabledIsUpdated() {

  ...
  this.zone.run(() => {
    isGeoLocationButtonEnabled = someValue;
  });
  ...
}
```